# Build Angular Application without restart by taking the new changes?

Tags: angular, frontend

When you do some changes to your Angular Application, I don't want the entire application to get restarted rather I want the changes to be taken that is done to the application and build the application without a restart. Where should I do the changes?

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: you'll have to share a bit more info; are you using Webpack? are you using Angular CLI? Usually you will need a restart because all of the code has to be reloaded, it can't really unload and load the modules.

Comment: Your project is either AngularJS (version <2.0), or Angular (version >2.0) - you should remove the tag that doesn't apply.

Comment: You're looking for something called "live reload" Its typically part of helper applications like webpack or NPM that create a server. If you're using Angular CLI try `ng serve --live-reload true`

Comment: (Auto) App restart is kind of normal behavior during app dev..